# My java thread code doesn't do what I want

Tags: java, multithreading

Why does the following code have `Thread-0` output 6 lines when `Thread-1` only outputs 3?

```
public class NameList{

    private List names = new ArrayList();
    public synchronized void addName(String name){
        names.add(name);
    }

    public synchronized void print(){
        for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(names.get(i)+" ");
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        final NameList nl = new NameList();
        for (int i = 0; i <2; i++) {

            new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    nl.addName("A");
                    nl.addName("B");
                    nl.addName("C");
                    nl.print();
                }
            }.start();

        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A Thread-1
B Thread-1
C Thread-1
A Thread-0
B Thread-0
C Thread-0
A Thread-0
B Thread-0
C Thread-0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> why does Thread-0 output 6 times and thread-1 3?????

Because each thread is spitting out the message based on the number of `NameList.names`:

```
// the threads share the same `NameList`
final NameList nl = new NameList();
...
nl.addName("A");
...
for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
```

Since `names` is shared between the threads, you are modifying the list in both threads.  The first thread adds 3 names and must be finishing before the 2nd thread runs.  Then the 2nd one adds another 3 and spits out 6.

If you want 2 threads to be updating the same list, you should protect it by using a concurrent collection or my doing the adds inside of a `synchronized (names) {` block.  Your code is working because `System.out.print()` is a synchronized class so it is causes the memory to be updated between threads.  If you removed the `print()` calls, each thread would most likely see `names` as being empty when they run.  They also could cause the `List` to be corrupted or other badness.

As to why `Thread-1` spits out the 3 *before* `Thread-0`, the threads are started at the same time and it is a race condition to see which one goes first.

Answer (score 0):

Because each thread is adding 3 names to the list, so, after the second thread has run, you have 6 names added, and one of the two threads prints them all.